# C# multithreading with locks resulting in a deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, deadlock

I got this code running in a Task:

```
foreach (a in as) // yield return
{
   component.Notify(...); // This component locks internally.
   component.PropertyChanged += (o, args) =>
   {
       // Cancel out of task by adding another screen.
       MainWindow.AddContent(new OtherComponent()); // WPF
   }
}
```

Now, when the task is cancelled at the wrong moment the .Notify function is still called after it already cancelled because the task is still running. What I want is when the .PropertyChanged event is called there should no more .Notify calls after that. I can of course fix this with a rather simple boolean in the loop that cancels this the next iteration, something like:

```
foreach (a in as) // yield return
{
   if (requestCancel)
       return;
   component.Notify(...); // This component locks internally.
   component.PropertyChanged += (o, args) =>
   {
       requestCancel = true;
   }
}
```

One of the problems here is that the `foreach (a in as)` statement can take a while to return the next iteration, so it can take a long while before it is actually cancelled. I tried with a lock around the requestCancel operations and then check if the requestCancel is true, but this results in a deadlock because `component` is using a lock internally on all operations. I cannot change this as it's a third party component. I also tried a semaphore, a readerwriterlock but I always end up with a deadlock. Such as this:

```
foreach (a in as) // yield return
{
   _semaphore.WaitOne();
   if (requestCancel)
       return;

   component.Notify(...); // This component locks internally.
   component.PropertyChanged += (o, args) =>
   {
       _semaphore.WaitOne();
       requestCancel = true;
   }
   _semaphore.Release();
}
```

Basically, the .Notify is blocked because the PropertyChanged is still being executed (due to both using a lock internally). Which in turn results in the situation that the PropertyChanged is waiting for the semaphore or readerwriterlock while the other block never releases the semaphore because it is waiting for the PropertyChanged to complete due to the lock.

I really need to cancel out of this code as soon as possible and the .Notify cannot be called anymore after the user cancelled it. After fiddling with this for a while I ran out of idea's. If anything is unclear, don't hesitate to ask for further information.

Comment: _Code more, text less_

Comment: There isn't that much more code to work with, unfortunately. I did edit to add the semaphore part (new Semaphore(1,1)).

Comment: So there is a shared `lock` call to `Notify()` and `PropertyChanged()`?

Comment: Where is the event for `component.PropertyChanged` being invoked? Since it's not being called inside your loop, some other code must be calling it from elsewhere.

Comment: @Tesj, yes there is. The component.PropertyChanged is invoked in that specific component.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Both methods start with the lock statement, like function Notify(...) { lock(myLock) { // the actual code } }. The same is done with the methods that call the PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

I think, all the code is executed on one thread like this:

1. Enter Notify()
2. Invoke PropertyChanged handler
3. Leave Notify()

In that case the semaphore will always block your code because in step 2 you wait for the semaphore to be signaled but this happens only after step 3. Try this:

```
foreach (a in as) // yield return
{
    component.PropertyChanged += (o, args) => requestCancel = true;

    component.Notify(...);

    // break out of the loop here to prevent getting next item from the enumerator
    if (requestCancel)
        break;
}

// do whatever you want to do after cancel
if (requestCancel)
    MainWindow.AddContent(new OtherComponent());
```

Comment: That won't work unfortunately because the .Notify(...) resets the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: ok, see my update, sorry for the formatting, it doesn't work for me very well

Comment: I already have that, the problem is that the foreach (a in as) can take quite long and this isn't feasable. When the user presses cancel (thats the firing of the propertychanged) it should cancel immediately, not after waiting for minutes.